# Force JavaScript reload just once a day

Tags: javascript, optimization, browser-cache

If the JavaScript's **?random** would be the current date - would it then loaded just once a day?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://external.example.com/bookmarklet.js?random"></script>
```

The background of my question is that I don't want that it stays forever in the cache but I'm also looking for a way to save some bandwith and speed things up. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the cache expiration header?

Comment: @Pointy, may be because it's not 100% cross-browser way? Or he just can't tune server in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a date or timestamp onto the end of the included js filename does make it reload itself if it has been cached by the user's browser.

If you want to use JavaScript to make this timestamp you can dynamically include your external js file like so:

```
var the_time = new Date();
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "test.js?" + the_time.getDate() + the_time.getMonth() + the_time.getFullYear());
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

I have chosen to make a timestamp from the day, month, and year, so it will change everyday.

Comment: Thanks for you example. I tried to implement it into my code. Is this correct? `javascript:javascript:(function(){
var the_time = new Date();
  new_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');
 new_script.type='text/javascript';
 new_script.src='http://example.com/js/bookmarklet.js?x=' + the_time.getDate() + the_time.getMonth() + the_time.getFullYear());
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_script);
})();` It's the first time I'm creating something with Javascript and I'm not sure if `var the_time = new Date();` is valid in that context.

Comment: I would try copying my code exactly into your "(function() {COPY CODE TO HERE})();" code. Then just change "test.js" to whatever the external js file is called.

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Sorry, I'm new to JS and bookmarklets. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)  So any help welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If your page is generated with PHP, you could do this:

```
<script src="http://external.example.com/bookmarklet.js?<?php echo date('Ymd'); ?>"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if that timestamp was adjusted to a certain time of the day (midnight, for example). This can't be done in HTML, but I found some PHP that will do the job: [from PHP Freaks](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=224745.0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work exactly like you need, just note that you write only the date part, without the time.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than once per day, I think you need to refresh the client's cache whenever the javascript changes - or as an approximation, when you upgrade or restart the application. Not sure what's the best practice in PHP, but in Python I would generate a random upon application startup, store it in a global variable, and use that in every URL of the resources you provide, be it JS or CSS. Libraries like jQuery or YUI etc. only need to be reload when there's a new release, and you might want to serve them from a CDN.